# MySQL CSV Import

Tags: mysql

I am currently importing a large data set from a CSV file and I keep getting the error duplicate primary key. The issue is I cannot add a new column to the csv for an autoincrement column in the database.

Is there a way while importing to make it skip a field via the query?

I.e I have 2 columns in the CSV and 3 in the database where the 3rd is the primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a list of fields present in the file.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE tablename(col2,col3);
```